# What is the difference between a web service hosted within your application and the one hosted over the internet?

Tags: java

What is the difference between a web service hosted within your application and the one hosted over the internet? And the complexities involved in consuming both of them?

Please can somebody explain this?

Answer (score 1):

Logically it doesn't matter who is hosting it. Basically this should be transparent. The only thing is that when it's hosted locally the performance (when calling it) will probably be better as the data doesn't need to travel over the Internet but just in say your local network.

Comment: so there won't be any complexities while consuming internal or external webservices.. i am sorry.. i am new to this, so just trying to understand

Comment: With respect to consuming them - no, no difference, you consume both in the same way. That should be transparent.